# How can I avoid "RPC Server is unavailable" when a user closes Outlook, and my app is using OLE Automation?

Tags: outlook, outlook-object-model

My application uses the Outlook object model.  Outlook is an out-of-process COM server.  Before Outlook 2007, if the user would close Outlook while my app had a reference to it, Outlook would stay running in a hidden state.  In Outlook 2007, if the user closes Outlook, the process closes and my application receives a "RPC server is unavailable".  Outlook is ignoring my apps reference.

How do I get Outlook 2007 to respect my application's reference to it, and do what it used to do in Outlook 2000 (stay running until my app released the reference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the Quit event off the application object and release your references to outlook etc.

I think there is also a reg hack to make it behave as before ..

arrha .. just found the msdn article with the registry path http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239276.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  That's the answer I was looking for!